# Is it possible to direct sound from one application to speakers and another to headset?

Tags: macos, audio

I was wondering if it would be possible to direct the sound from Spotify to speakers, while keeping Skype or Google chat to my headset? I am using a mac mini by the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10977/how-do-i-adjust-the-sound-settings-on-my-computer-and-in-skype-for-mac-os-x-lion

It has detailed instructions on how to select audio devices for Skype.
In general, most applications (especially VoIP software) will have the option to select devices manually and to override system audio default.

EDIT: Seems this has been asked before in a similar fashion:

http://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijackpro/

is what you want, see also:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563978/mac-force-another-application-to-use-a-specific-audio-device

Comment: cool, it turns out both Skype and GTalk allows me to choose the device.. I wonder if it's possible to do this for any application, in other words, for instance spotify is directed to computer speakers, while VLC is directed to stereo via HDMI

Comment: I have amended my answer to reflect your needs.